# How do I require modules installed with npm globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, read-eval-print-loop

I have installed `some-npm-module` globally, but I get an error when I `require()` it:

```
$ node    
> const module = require('some-npm-module')
> import module from 'some-npm-module'

Error: Cannot find module 'some-npm-module'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at repl:1:12
    at realRunInThisContextScript (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:98:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:24:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:313:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
```

Core Node modules do seem to work without issue. The following produces no errors:

```
const http = require('http');
```

Why does this happen? Am I installing the module correctly?

Note that in this case I need to use the npm module in the **terminal**, not in a certain project.

Comment: Explain what do you mean " i can't use it in the terminal " ?

Comment: Try installing locally with `npm install some-npm-module`. (`--save` if appropriate)

Comment: Type this `$ npm install some-npm-module --save`

Comment: What command did you run to install it globally? `npm install "some-npm-module" -g`?

Comment: @karina I checked before posting my answer and my solution **does** indeed work for the REPL (that's the name for the Node interpreter when you run it from the terminal if you weren't sure). Try it yourself and check if it works for you, and if not, edit it into the question (also, it's a good idea to add a comment that starts with `@Aurora0001` so I receive the message and reply more quickly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only install modules globally if you plan to call them on the command line, [according to the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally):

> If you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally. On the other hand, if you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's require, then you want to install locally.

This is because `require()` doesn't look in the global modules directory, so it'll never find `some-npm-module` if it's installed there.

Installing locally with `npm install some-npm-module` should resolve your issue and allow you to require from the REPL (as long as you consistently run the REPL from the **same directory**).

Comment: thank You so much... the key here u should install `npm install some-npm-module` on a directory that have `package.json`... if it install on a directory that dont have `package.json`,,npm will throw error `no such file or directory, open package.json`... thank again...

Answer (score -1):

### Please Remove entire node_modules folder and re-install

- > **rm -rf node_modules**
- > **npm install**

Comment: Why would this help? They say in the question that the install was global.

Answer (score -1):

After installing an npm module globally, to use it in your current project/dir, just link it.

npm link module_name

It should work.